# Really slow pbf geoserver requests from openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I have a shapefile hosted on a local geoserver that represents canada's land border, which is about 30MB of size. I want to create a vector tile layer of it with openlayers.
Here is the piece of code:

```
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new VectorTileLayer({
      source: new VectorTile({
        format: new MVT(),
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ogsl:canada_land@EPSG%3A4326@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

It works fine, the it sometimes renders really slowly. It can somtimes take up to 30 seconds for a tile of a few kB to load. But it is not always like this. It sometimes takes a few ms for the same size of request. Here is an example:
[image: loading time differences]

I fail to understand what I can change to improve this. Is it on my geoserver that the problem resides, or more on the client side, how I call the layer?
Any tips would be really helpful!

Comment: If you are using a single line/polygon per province, you can try to subdivide them (i.e break them so that their is no more than +- 100 vertices per sub-line or sub-polygon), that way intersections are much much much faster (see this [blog](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html) for more details)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the slow loads are when GeoServer is actually "drawing" your tile and the quick ones are when the output is already stored on disk in the GeoWebCache.

A lot of speed issues are related to how much data is being loaded and rendered (or turned into pbf in this case), simply reading a lot of data from disk takes time. Much of that time will be wasted if there is a lot of detail that is below the pixel size of the output. So simplifying the data, storing it on a faster drive will help. If you are using Windows then moving to Linux will give a 20% or better speed up, you may also get an improvement by switching storage to a PostGIS database.